# Finding an object in MongoDb that has a value within a range

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

MongoDb 3.4.9

I have objects that look like this:

```
startIpNum:16779264
endIpNum:16781311
locId:47667

startIpNum:16781312
endIpNum:16785407
locId:879228
```

etc

How can I find just the object that has a range (between startIpNum and endIpNum) for 16779300?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({ startIpNum:{ $gte: 16779300 }, endIpNum:{$lte: 16779300} })
```

It includes both upper and lower limit

Comment: I think you've got your `$gte` and `$lte` swapped.